# Does Solr support Filter Aggregations?

Tags: solr

I am new with Solr and wondering if it supports generating a facet (aggregation) based on a filter.

E.g. Count of products which name starts with letter A.

Something similar to ElasticSearch feature bellow:
https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-aggregations-bucket-filter-aggregation.html#search-aggregations-bucket-filter-aggregation

If it's not supported out of the box, how would you solve this?

Thanks you in advance,

Comment: faceting is available in solr...https://lucene.apache.org/solr/guide/7_1/faceting.html

Comment: https://lucene.apache.org/solr/guide/7_2/the-stats-component.html